# Expression Engine module/plugin for audio and video--the best?

Tags: plugins, expressionengine

I'm building a church site that wants audio/video functionality.

What are your recommendations for an audio/video (can be separate) plugin?  Needs to be very simple and integrate w/ EE as well as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had good experiences with the FLV player plugin from 5 pieces.

http://5pieces.com/addons/flv-media-player/

Once it's set up and integrated it's pretty easy for your users to deal with.

Comment: This does audio, or just video?

Comment: It can play mp3s - not sure about other formats tbh.

Answer (score 4):

I build quite a few church websites and I always go for http://mediaelementjs.com/ - it's HTML5 with Flash/Silverlight fallback whilst also being able to support Vimeo/YouTube.

It is EE agnostic but coupled with something like @mrw's [Antenna](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/antenna) it's a great tool.

Comment: Exactly the same tool I use for stand-alone videos. 

Some clients need a bit of assistance with managing video or don't have clear hosting options. In that case I tend to move them to YouTube or Vimeo and have them manage the vids with DevDemon's Channel Videos.

Answer (score 3):

I used [Wyvern Video](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wyvern-video) recently and if they are happy to host on YouTube or Vimeo it couldn't be easier for clients to use. You can link it directly to their YouTube channel so they just get a list of their own videos to select from.

Answer (score 1):

For the backend stuff I always use DevDemon's Channel Files add-on (http://www.devdemon.com/channel_files/)  linked to an Amazon S3 account as to keep the upload/download/streaming load off my server as much as possible. Works great and your EE editors will love it!

And yes it does feel weird to build church sites using a DevDemon plugin ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend mediaelements - used it for both separate video and audio and is superb for both with fallback for older browsers built in.

Comment: Thanks @Darrel...this is a pretty old question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The new [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/news/) looks pretty slick too.